# Calendar object keeps printing March as the month and 1 as they year

Tags: java, date, javafx, calendar

Does anyone know why my calendar object keeps printing March as the month and 1 as they year?  Is there a way to set the calendar to the current month and day?

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import javafx.application.Application;

public class Calendar extends Application{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();

    // Create a calendar
    GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    Date time = new Date();
    calendar.setTime(time);

    // Create title
    Text header = new Text(getMonth(calendar.MONTH) + ", " + calendar.YEAR);

    // place title in pane
    pane.setTop(header);
    BorderPane.setAlignment(header, Pos.CENTER);

    Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: What is `getMonth(...)`? If you are using `Calendar` you need to use code like `calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)` and `calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)`. If you are using Java 8, you should not use `Calendar` at all but should use [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html).

Comment: @Rachel Please strip down your code before posting, to the [absolute minimum](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) needed to show your issue. The JavaFX stuff is irrelevant to your question about date-time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## java.time

By the way, this kind of work is much easier in the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework now built into Java 8 and later. These new classes supplant the old java.util.Date/.Calendar classes that have proved so troublesome.

Determine today's date.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of ( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now ( zoneId );
```

Generate a String representation of that date object using a certain format.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "M, yyyy" );
String output = today.format ( formatter );
```

Better yet, generate a String representation in a localized format.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatterLocalized = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate ( FormatStyle.FULL ).withLocale ( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH );
String outputLocalized = today.format ( formatterLocalized );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "today: " + today + " is: " + output + " which in localized format is: " + outputLocalized );
```

When run.

> today: 2015-10-17 is: 10, 2015 which in localized format is: samedi 17 octobre 2015

Comment: This is exactly what I needed!  I am using Java 8, so the Calendar and Date classes aren't doing what I need them too.

Comment: Another question, is there a way to figure out the day of the week that the current month starts on?  For example, the answer for October 2015 would be Thursday because October 1 starts on a Thursday.

Comment: @Rachel Comments are not the place for additional questions. First search StackOverflow to see if your new question has already been posted (it has, *many* times over). If not yet asked, post a fresh Question.

Answer (score 2):

```
Text header = new Text(getMonth(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)
        + ", " + calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
```

The Calendar.get method uses int constants to get the specific MONTH/YEAR field.
Mind that month is I believe counted from 0.

Java 8 data/time classes are much nicer (though a bit overwhelming in mass at the beginning).

Answer (score 0):

Editing to give more explanation :

get and set methods on the Calendar object will expect the field number/positions to return the value, and these numbers are defined as  constants, like MONTH, YEAR, DAY, DAY_OF_MONTH etc.,

So, when you use `calendar.Month` it will just return you the value of the field number instead of the actual month. You will need to use this in tandem with get / set methods to get the actual values in your calendar instance.

Example

```
Text header = new Text(getMonth(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + ", " + calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
```

Comment: Please add some explanation. Imparting the underlying logic is more important than just giving the code, because it helps the OP and other readers fix this and similar issues themselves.